# SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity or SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute?

Tags: c#

To disable security checks what should I set? `SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute` or `SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity`?

Which of these versions is corrrect?

```
    [DllImport("Native.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern void Method(...
```

or

```
    [DllImport("Native.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
    public static extern void Method(...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both do the same thing. The class is named `SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute`, but when annotating attributes in general, you can omit the suffix `Attribute`.